# Oracle PL/SQL ORA-00904: invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to declare a string and use it in a select statement but it's throwing ORA-00904: invalid identifier.

```
DECLARE
    var_laufi VARCHAR2(20) := 'JEIV';
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE q'[
    WITH aux AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            zbuag_id AS ca_dat
        FROM
            vw_penddv2
        WHERE
            category = 'Issue'
    ), aux2 AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            vkont AS ca_lock
        FROM
            cdc.uap_dfkklocks@rbip
        WHERE
            laufi = ]'
                      || var_laufi
                      || q'[
            AND tdate >= to_char(sysdate, 'YYYYMMDD')
    )
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        aux    a
        FULL OUTER JOIN aux2   b ON b.ca_lock = a.ca_dat
    WHERE
        ( a.ca_dat IS NULL
          OR b.ca_lock IS NULL )
    ]'
                      ;
END;
```

However, if I just try to display the variable itself, it works fine.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE
    var_laufi VARCHAR2(20) := 'JEIV';
BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line(var_laufi);
END;
```

Result:

```
JEIV


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

I'm missing something here but I can't figure out what is it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamic SQL is *evil* if you misuse it. Rule of thumb: never execute it if you didn't check what you're executing! How? Display the statement. Here's how:

```
DECLARE
   var_laufi  VARCHAR2 (20) := 'JEIV';
   var_str    VARCHAR2 (2000);
BEGIN
   var_str := q'[
    WITH aux AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            zbuag_id AS ca_dat
        FROM
            vw_penddv2
        WHERE
            category = 'Issue'
    ), aux2 AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            vkont AS ca_lock
        FROM
            cdc.uap_dfkklocks@rbip
        WHERE
            laufi = ]' || var_laufi || q'[
            AND tdate >= to_char(sysdate, 'YYYYMMDD')
    )
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        aux    a
        FULL OUTER JOIN aux2   b ON b.ca_lock = a.ca_dat
    WHERE
        ( a.ca_dat IS NULL
          OR b.ca_lock IS NULL )
    ]';

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (var_str);
END;
/
```

The result (formatted):

```
WITH
   aux
   AS
      (SELECT DISTINCT zbuag_id AS ca_dat
         FROM vw_penddv2
        WHERE category = 'Issue'),
   aux2
   AS
      (SELECT DISTINCT vkont AS ca_lock
         FROM cdc.uap_dfkklocks@rbip
        WHERE     laufi = JEIV                                  --> here
              AND tdate >= TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'YYYYMMDD'))
SELECT *
  FROM aux a FULL OUTER JOIN aux2 b ON b.ca_lock = a.ca_dat
 WHERE (   a.ca_dat IS NULL
        OR b.ca_lock IS NULL)
```

See the comment? `where laufi = JEIV` is invalid, should have been enclosed into single quotes.

Also, is `tdate` really a string? You're comparing it to `sysdate` represented as a string in specified format. If that's so, bad, BAD idea to store `DATE` datatype values as strings.

Comment: I've done this to bypass the issue with the quotes. Is there any more elegant way to do it?: WHERE
            laufi = ]'
                      || '''|| var_laufi
                      ||'''
                      || q'[
            AND tdate >= to_char(sysdate, 'YYYYMMDD')

Comment: Yeah, about the dates. We've highlighted this to the DBAs many times, but they're not keen on changing the design :(

Comment: Single quotes ... sometimes I concatenate `chr(39)` as it clearly shows what my intention is. True, a little bit more typing, but prevents errors. As of dates: oh well. Good luck with such a colleagues.

Comment: Dynamic SQL isn't "evil".  It just misused by those with bad intentions ;)

Answer (score 0):

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_PARENT_PRODUCT_JOINS (V_C_ID in number, c1 out sys_refcursor)
is

V_sql varchar2(2000);

Begin

-----------(STEP_1_JOINS)---------------------

```
   V_sql:=
   '
   SELECT Country.C_id,Country.C_name,product.C_id
   FROM Country                                                                                 
   INNER JOIN Product
   ON country.C_id = product.C_id
   where V_C_ID='||V_C_ID;
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE(V_SQL);
```

-------------(STEP_2_TRUNCATE DATA)----------------

```
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE Product_det';   



dbms_output.put_line(V_SQL);
open c1 for V_sql;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
```

End;
error;
ORA-00904: "V_C_ID": invalid identifier

Comment: how to declare the dynamic variables

Comment: Are you posting a question as a answer to an old question already answered? If you have your own question, post a new one, don't post an answer asking a question, because you are not going to get an answer.